# Stay subscribed to an array of Subjects

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I have a main file that creates and destroys instances of a class `Child`. The Child instances are kept in an array (`childArr`) within main and I want a way to listen for events from all of those Child instances.

Each Child has a Subject exposed and I want to keep a subscription to all those Subjects that remains up to date as Child instances are added to or removed from the Array.

[This stackblitz project is the simplest version I can come up with](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ckb6qj?file=index.ts). As it is it works while I manually add each child subject to the `merge()`  method (lines 22-24). The commented out lines at the bottom (lines 28-30) are what I had *hoped* to do but that don't seem to work.

I would love someone to explain the difference between the merge on lines 22-24 and the one on line 28-30, why the first works and the second doesn't and hopefully how I can make the second one work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `merge` operator does accept array of observable as a prams but `childArr` is an array of `Child` instances rather than an array of observables

Comment: @RafiHenig - You are right! I still can't get it to work though. I've added some short example example code that shows what I'm trying. If you wanted to have a look at that and see if you can point out where I'm going wrong I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `merge` operator, when passed an `ArrayLike` is much like [FROM](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from) operator where each item in the array is wrapped with a new Observable.

Simply put:

`merge([1,2,3])` equals to `from([1,2,3)]`

Passing `merge` an array of Observables would results in each item getting wrapped with a new Observable as demonstrated below:

```
merge([of(1), of(2)]).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(isObservable(x)) // true 
});
```

To avoid that consider using the [SPREAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator as in the following example:

```
merge(...childArr.map(x => x.feed$)).subscribe(e => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Great answer! That actually explains some of the error messages I was getting. I was only dimly aware of the spread operator but it has done the trick. Thank you.